# How much business code is ok to have in a Factory?

Tags: python, design-patterns, architecture, software-design

I'm learning patterns using problems that I actually have. So, sorry for some too basic questions.

I have a Factory that creates four different types of products:

```
class ProductFactory:
    def product_a(self):
        return ProductA()

    def product_b(self):
        return ProductB()

    def product_c(self):
        return ProductC()

    def product_d(self):
        return ProductD()
```

But **ProductA** is a little bit complex. In fact **ProductA** is built using two different classes because those are different data sources that actual have to be put together in a intricate way to generate an useful **ProductA**.

So, my doubt:

Is that ok to have my **product_a()** method in the **ProductFactory** to be responsible to mess around with those two data sources, do everything necessary and finally  build the neat **ProductA**? Or **product_a()** is not supposed to know anything about how **ProductA** is mounted using a considerable business logic?

For example, only a illustration, my **ProductA** would look something like:

```
    class ProductFactory:
    
        def __init__(self, data_source1=None, data_source2=None):
            self.data_source1 = data_source1
            self.data_source2 = data_source2

        def product_a(self):
    
            formated_data = self.data_source1.do_creepy_stuff()
            messed_data = self.data_source2.mess_a_lot()
    
            final_data = formated_data.update(messed_data)
    
            return ProductA(final_data)
    
        def product_b(self):
    
            return ProductB()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    data_source1 = DataSource1('my_file')
    data_source2 = DataSource2('my_directory')
    
    factory = ProductFactory(data_source1, data_source2)

    product = factory.product_a()
```

In case that idea is ok, would be better to pass the data sources as parameter to the **product_a()** method or as parameter to the factory constructor (like in example)?

In general... I'm very confused to let the factory having the responsibility to know how to execute methods from those data sources (like **data_source1.do_creepy_stuff()**)... I guess any change in my data sources classes could contaminate my factory.

But at the same moment, I actual have a **ProductA** that uses to different data sources as its parts **AND** those data sources have to be manipulated before mounting **ProductA**, by the simply fact those data sources are also used by other parts of the software that has nothing for to do with products.

So, I'm really working hard to understand the best way to deal with that situation and a ***factory*** seem to be the best solution, but... there's those doubts...

Comment: Your first bit of code looks wrong as you had 4 `product_a` functions. You may want to change them to `a, b, c, d`.

Comment: I'd like to ask a different question: how many factory classes should you have in Python. Since Python uses duck typing, has meta classes and everything is very dynamic, factory are rarely seen in it.

Comment: You right about the 'a' methods. It was a copy/paste issue. I've fixed.

Comment: How many factories? Well... I was thinking about having a single factory to create 4 or 5 "products", every product having lots of coding before being able to actual give birth to the product. And that "lots of code" is because different data sources used by each product...